# What does the expression "la tête dans les étoiles" mean?

Tags: sens, expressions

What does the expression "la tête dans les etoiles" mean? I've heard it in tons of songs, like in *Paname* by Slimane

Answer (score 2):

In the song *Paname*, I understand it as some sort of daydreaming about hopes of fame (maybe it plays on the double meaning "étoile" can have in French, just like in English, ie the stellar object but also a famous actor or singer, as this song is about Slimane's dreams to become a star).

In other contexts, the metaphor can be slightly different, but most of the times it refers to some dreaming or high hopes, possibly detached from mundane matters. More down to earth, if you spend for instance the night outside and look up to a cloudless sky and admire the stars, you could also say, a bit on a poetic note: "j'ai la tête dans les étoiles".

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Im really grateful

Answer (score 1):

Le *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (dir. A. Rey, ed. Le Robert, 2008) en parle en ce qui a trait à des expressions où *étoile* est un symbole du *ciel étoilé*, dans le cas qui nous intéresse ici pour « **(être) dans un état de rêve, d'idéalisme absolu** » ; on la dit attestée dans les années [1990](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la%20t%C3%AAte%20dans%20les%20%C3%A9toiles&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cla%20t%C3%AAte%20dans%20les%20%C3%A9toiles%3B%2Cc0) et on réfère à *ne plus toucher terre* (DHLF/Rey), que le TLFi mentionne en emploi figuré pour le mot [*terre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/terre) dans le sens de « perdre contact avec la réalité » (avec l'exemple : « Capus ne touche plus terre. Il marche à dix centimètres, au moins, du sol. Il fait pour Micheau une pièce qui passera dix jours après La Veine. » (Renard, *Journal*) au TLFi ), alors qu'au [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne_plus_toucher_terre) ce serait « être heureux »...

On dit aussi que la locution « (avoir/être) la tête dans les étoiles » est « fréquemment utilisée comme titre, [...] souvent en référence à l'astronomie et à la restauration gastronomique » et on la compare à d'autres expressions comme *être aux anges*, *ne pas toucher terre* et *(être/flotter) sur un (petit) nuage rose* ([*On Va le Dire Comme ça: Dictionnaire des Expressions Quotidiennes*](https://books.google.com/books?id=d-wcAQAAIAAJ&q=%22la%20t%C3%AAte%20dans%20les%20%C3%A9toiles%22&dq=%22la%20t%C3%AAte%20dans%20les%20%C3%A9toiles%22), Bernet/Rézeau, ed. Balland, 2008).

Comment: Être *si heureux* qu’on ne *touche plus terre* serait-il une façon de concilier les deux définitions. Du moins, j’accepterais les deux nuances...

Answer (score 0):

Cet expression est complètement semblable à l’expression « head in the clouds » en anglais.